# How to get the learned atomic clauses from Z3?

Tags: z3py

I need to find the atoms that are the consequences of a formula.  For example, the list of consequences of

```
p() & (p()=>q())
```

is `[p(), q()]`.  When checking for the satisfiability of this formula, Z3 learns many clauses, presumably including that p and q must be true.

The Z3 Solver class has a method, called `units` that "Return an AST vector containing all currently inferred units".  It looks like what I need.  Yet, the following program prints an empty list:

```
p = Bool("p")
q = Bool("q")
s = Solver()
s.add(And(p, Implies(p, q)))
print(s.check())
print(s.units())
```

I tried it on several formulas, but always got an empty list.  I asked on [Z3's issue list](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5436) to get more documentation, to no avail.

Could someone give a working example where `units()` does not return an empty list, and explain what it does ?

Note: Another method is to check every atom `a` occurring in the formula, to see if both `a` and `Not(a)` are consistent with the formula, but that is a time-consuming operation that I try to improve by using `units`.

Comment: Strangely, the `non_units` method of Solver returns `[p, q]` in my example.  An explanation of that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact, I don't think anymore that using `units` will bring a speed boost compared to the method proposed at the end of the original question.

The reason is that, if  `a` is a learned clause, checking whether atom `a` and `Not(a)` are consistent with the formula is immediate: there is no search involved if you use the incremental solver capability of Z3.

Maybe that's why `units` is not a popular method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `consequences` method instead. Here's an example:

```py
from z3 import *

p = Bool("p")
q = Bool("q")
s = Solver()
s.add(And(p, Implies(p, q)))
print(s.consequences([], [p, q]))
```

This prints:

```
(sat, [Implies(True, p), Implies(True, q)])
```

If you "squint," you'll see that z3 is telling us `p` and `q` must always be true; which is what I believe you're after.

The `consequences` method is explained here: [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-consequences](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-consequences)

In short, you can give it what's assumed (the first argument, which I used the empty list above), and based on the constraints you've asserted, it returns what consequences follow.

Comment: Thanks.  I was aware of this function too.  The problem is when the theory has a million atoms and only a few consequences.  A call to consequences must list all the atoms in the second argument.  I was hoping that units() would give me the few consequences directly.